# Jquery UI Datepicker - if user enter last 2 digit of year in input field it should show as 4 digit of year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
$("body").on("focusin", ".date_field", function(e) {
    $(this).datepicker({
        yearRange: "c-40:c+10",
        minDate: $(this).data("minimum-date"),
        maxDate: $(this).data("maximum-date"),
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
    });
});
```

Above code I used to render the datepicker, when user enter year in 2 digit like 12/08/22 it should show as 12/08/2022

Comment: Can you make a runnable stacksnippet with HTML and all that reproduces the issue? Use the `<>` icon on the editor toolbar. You will need to add CDN references to the jquery stuff in the HTML section.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    yearRange: "c-40:c+10",
    minDate: $(this).data("minimum-date"),
    maxDate: $(this).data("maximum-date"),
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
  });
  $("#datepicker").blur(function() {
    var cDate = $(this).val().split("/");
    if (cDate[2].length == 2) {
      cDate[2] = "20" + cDate[2];
    }
    $(this).val(cDate.join("/"));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>
```

This takes the text, splits it on `/` and the checks the year. There are a lot of pitfalls with this. Here is a more complex example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    yearRange: "c-40:c+10",
    minDate: $(this).data("minimum-date"),
    maxDate: $(this).data("maximum-date"),
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
  });
  $("#datepicker").blur(function() {
    var cDate = new Date($(this).val());
    $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", cDate));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>
```

This tries to convert the value into a Date and then uses `$.datepicker.formatDate()` to format it back.

> Format a date into a string value with a specified format.

So if the user enters 1/1/99, or they enter 08/30/22, it will work in both ways.